# grouped_collection_select for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, so I have a model with a schema:

```
  create_table "areas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "province"
    t.string   "city"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The entries would look something like this (minus the date time fields):

```
1, Ontario, Ottawa
2, Ontario, Toronto
3, Ontario, Hamilton
4, British Columbia, Vancouver
5, Ontario, Niagara Falls
6, British Columbia, Surrey
7, Alberta, Calgary
8, Alberta, Edmonton
```

How can I create a grouped_collection_select which will:

1. List all areas using :city as text
2. Group the areas using distinct :province
3. Return the area_id for my form

Comment: Have you thought about using the [`countries`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) or [`cities`](https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities) gems?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a gem known as [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), that way you can really easily create a grouped select input like this:

```
f.input :area, collection: @areas, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :last
```

The method named called in `group_method` will be called to generate in item in the group, and your `@areas` collection would need to follow this format:

```
 { 'Ontario' => ['Ottawa', 'Toronto'] }
```